# Data Being Requested from Tor Socks Server

Tags: c, proxy, tor, socks

I am doing some playing around with the Tor project code and I wanted to see if it was possible to append a string to the data being sent or even just log the data to the console before it gets encrypted. I am doing this privately inside my own network btw.

I am still unfamiliar with the code but I have been looking in connection_edge.c to find where the socks server receives the data but I am having a hard time pinpointing it. If anyone familiar could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.